# Generate PDF from HTML using JQuery and jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jspdf

Here is the code to generate PDF from HTML using jQuery and jspdf.There are no events occurs when the "download pdf" button clicks. 
jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#download_pdf').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter'),
      source = $('#table_stock')[0],
      specialElementHandlers = {
        '#table_stock': function(element, renderer) {
          return true
        }
      }
    margins = {
      top: 60,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 40,
      width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
      source, margins.left, margins.top, {
        'width': margins.width,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      },
      function(dispose) {
        pdf.save('Stockreport.pdf');
      },
      margins
    )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stock_report" id="table_stock"></div>
<button id="download_pdf" class="btndownloadt_stock_report btn btn-primary">Download PDF</button>
```

Comment: any error message ?

Comment: You're passing null as source, due to $('#table_stock')[0] doesn't seems to exists in your HTML.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined @Natsathorn

Comment: there is no '1' in here. but let check where is it in your code

Comment: include this library https://mrrio.github.io/jspdf.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the lib include the lib as following because after adding this lib there is no error.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js'></script>
```

Another thing just use `$('#table_stock')` there is no requirment of `[0]`, if you are using `class` `selector` then `$('.stock_report')[0]`.

Comment: jspdf.debug.js:7640 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined @Ullas Hunka

Comment: Can you please tell me the libraries used by you?

Comment: jquery ui,jspdf,chosen @ Ullas Hunka

Comment: Now pdf works.Downloaded as a pdf file.But there is no content inside pdf.Shows undefined

Comment: does your div has some content. can you show me the log or create the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176315/discussion-between-ullas-hunka-and-saclt7).